# Backpress in WebView does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have app, a Activity and after click on button layout of activity changes with fragment layout, in layout I have only WEBVIEW. Then load the url pages all is clickable but then I click on back button it goes to activity, not previous page. Why is this?

```
 myWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"ACTION_UP");
                if(myWebView.canGoBack())
                Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"goBack");
                myWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Why does CanGoBack not work? only in Log show "ACTION_UP".

Comment: try to use interface for onclick, and in activity, use that interface method to call back button. in onBackPressed, check for canGoBack

Comment: @MohdAsifAhmed i i tried but (myWebView.canGoBack()) didint works

Comment: Please take more care with your writing on Stack Overflow. Chatty titles, slang, txtspk and please-halp begging all necessitate extra work from volunteer editors. It is helpful to use an English spell-checker and refrain from chat-style conversation when posting here.

Comment: may be that webview doesn't go any more back

Comment: try to add log
Log.d(TAG,"canGoBack value " + myWebView.canGoBack());
Paste this in onKeyDown and check, what value you are getting

Comment: it says canGoBack value = false

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't use `"{ }"` braces in your `if condition`

```
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
         && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

         Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"ACTION_UP");

         if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
              Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"goBack");
              myWebView.goBack();
         }

         return true;
    }
```

Comment: i did it but not helps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `KeyListener` to `WebView`, you can use `Activity's` `OnKeyDown` function like:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"ACTION_UP");
           if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
                Log.d(Constants.TAG_FRAGMENT,"goBack");
                myWebView.goBack();
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

From [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack()),

> canGoBack returns true if and only if this WebView has a back history
>   item

So, make sure you have proper back history for `webview` to redirect.

Comment: Again same problem

Comment: if `canGoBack()` returns false, then you might not have any back history in webview. Backhistory gets generated when you redirect from one page to another inside same webview.

Comment: Does this mean that if the same url but different tabs it will not work?

Comment: and what can i do ?

Comment: Different tab means Different webview object is getting initiated, hence both are not connected in any way(Like a normal browser tab in your pc); if you want user to go back, you have to make them redirect using only one webview. Back history will get generated only when user **redirects** using the `hyperlinks` available on a specific web page.

Comment: IF i open the stackoverflow page in webview and open some questions in it , after i want to go previous question what can i do ?

Comment: If you open the question links in same webview, you can go back to previous link, using `webview.canGoBack()` function

Comment: Consider by understanding following Scenario: **U open `stackoverflow.com` in webview > Click on any question link > Question page opens > Now Click back > Previous Page opens**. This previous page opening is handled by `OnKeyDown` function in my code